# Is there a way to fetch data from power bi visual?

Tags: python, powerbi, power-automate, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to automatically fetch the data from a power BI Visual (not from the dataset).

For e.g from a table visual from Power BI.

I tried using Power BI rest APIs but there is no option to get the data from visuals. The ‘/visuals’ API end point does not exist

I was able to export the data in a PDF format using Power Automate but this doesn’t help. Need it in csv format at least.

Can any one help me with this? Since our backend scripts are written in Python, a solution compatible with Python is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use [Execute Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries-in-group) and pass a DAX expression equivalent for the visual.